# Подставить адрес в массиве PHP

Tags: php, php7

Можно ли в PHP подставить адрес массиву?

Например вот структура `$_FILE`, что бы получить имя и размер файлов в портфолио массив будет выглядеть так:

```
$_FILE['name'][7]['portfolio'][0];
$_FILE['size'][7]['portfolio'][0];
```

Могу ли я каким нибудь образом поместить адрес `[7]['portfolio'][0]` в переменную и сделать, как то так?

```
$a = [7]['portfolio'][0];
$_FILE['name'].$a;

// P.S. Понимаю что это работать не будет, можно и что то подобное сделать?
```

-

```
[name] => Array(
        [6] => Array(
                [layer] => Снимок экрана (10).png
                [size] => whois_2.png
            )
        [7] => Array(
                [portfolio] => Array(
                        [0] => 2whois.png
                        [1] => DNS.png
                    )
            )
    )
...
[size] => Array(
        [6] => Array(
                [layer] => Снимок экрана (10).png
                [size] => whois_2.png
            )
        [7] => Array(
                [portfolio] => Array(
                        [0] => 2whois.png
                        [1] => DNS.png
                    )
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Обновлено:**  позволяет определять не все ключи.

Можно воспользоваться для вашей задачи замыканием ([Closure](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php)). Вот вариант:

```
<?php

function fixOffsets($k1, $k2 = null, $k3 = null)
{
    return function (array $arr) use ($k1, $k2, $k3) {
        $res = $arr[$k1] ;
        if ($k2 === null) return $res;
        $res = $res[$k2] ; 
        if ($k3 === null) return $res;
        return $res[$k3];
    };
};

$a = [
    'name' => [
        6 => [
            'layer' => "Снимок экрана (10).png",
            'size' => "3whois_2.png"
        ],
        7 => [
            'portfolio' => [
                0 => "whois.png",
                1 => "DNS.png"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'size' => [
        6 => [
            'layer' => "Снимок экрана (10).png",
            'size' => "4whois_2.png"
        ],
        7 => [
            'portfolio' => [
                0 => "2whois.png",
                1 => "2DNS.png"
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$extractor = fixOffsets(7, 'portfolio', 0);
var_dump($extractor($a['name']));
var_dump($extractor($a['size']));

$extractor = fixOffsets(6, 'size' );
var_dump($extractor($a['name']));
var_dump($extractor($a['size']));
```

**Описание:**

Вызов функции `fixOffsets($k1, $k2, $k3)` возвращает функцию-замыкание,у которой в области видимости зафиксированны переменные $k1, $k2, $k3 и которая:

- ожидает параметр - многомерный ассоциативный массив;
- возвращает требуемое значение из массива, переданного в качестве аргумента, используя переменные $k1, $k2, $k3 как ключи. Два последних ключа являются необязательными.

[Песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/89f31ab9c396fde5c49badc17cd31e8ffdc70bd9)

Comment: А нет погорячился с отметкой ответа `$extractor = fixOffsets(6, 'size', null);` так работать не будет

Comment: @Jarry Roxwell,  в постановке вопроса не было информации о произвольном кол-ве ключей. Я обновил свой ответ под новое условие.

Answer (score 0):

Доработанный ответ

> Можно воспользоваться для вашей задачи замыканием (Closure). Вот вариант:
>
> ### @Jigius

```
<?php

function fixOffsets(array $path)
{
  return function (array $arr) use ($path) {
    foreach($path as $val)
      if(empty($val)) return $arr;
      else $arr = $arr[$val];          
    return $arr;
  };
};

$a = [
  'name' => [
    6 => [
        'layer' => "Снимок экрана (10).png",
        'size' => "whois_2.png"
    ],
    7 => [
        'portfolio' => [
            0 => "2whois.png",
            1 => "DNS.png"
        ]
    ]
],
'size' => [
    6 => [
        'layer' => "Снимок экрана (10).png",
        'size' => "whois_2.png"
    ],
    7 => [
        'portfolio' => [
            0 => "2whois.png",
            1 => "2DNS.png"
        ]
    ]
  ]
];


//var_dump($a['name'][7]['portfolio'][0]);
//var_dump($a['size'][7]['portfolio'][0]);

$extractor = fixOffsets(array(7, 'portfolio', 0));
var_dump($extractor($a['name']));
var_dump($extractor($a['size']));

$extractor = fixOffsets(array(6, 'layer'));
var_dump($extractor($a['name']));
var_dump($extractor($a['size']));
```

А какие еще варианты решения данной задачи могут быть?